# Substituting part of a string starting at a position

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I'm trying to conditionally update part of a string starting at a specified location. I have something like this:

```
i = 0
bre = 'newtext'
with open(myfile, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        if i > 0 and line[98] == '1':
            print 'ok'
            line[1562] = bre
        i += 1
        # write line to a file
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    line[1562] = bre
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @norok2 - edited to reflect error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change an element of a string which is character to another string

```
line = line[:1562] + bre + line[1563:]

# to skip the length of your bre
line = line[:1562] + bre + line[(1562+len(bre)):]
```

example

```
bre = 'newtext'

myString = "asdfghjkl"

#replace character at index 2 with my string bre
myString = myString [:2]+ bre+ myString [3:]

print(myString)
```

```
asnewtextfghjkl
```

also string is not mutable like a list

you cannot go to an index and change the character

example

```
s = "abc"
a[1] = 'z' # is wrong because 'str' object does not support item assignment

s = a[:1] + 'z' + a[2:] #but this will work
# this takes the pointer s and points it a completely new string
```

FUN FACT:
that is the reason you can use string as a key in a dictionary but not a list. strings can be hashed

Comment: Thanks for your response Kuldeep. This is almost the behavior I am looking for, however, I'd like the new string to take the place of those 10 positions. By adding `myString`, it is increasing the length of the string. The string itself is a fixed width line.

Comment: I am glad it helped, please check I have added the update

Comment: You should probably also report why `s = 'hello'; s[3] = 'world'` is not working. From your texting it looks like while the above would not have worked, something like `s = 'hello'; s[3] = 'x'` would, but it does not.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I have added that to my response :)

Answer (score 2):

You provide too little context in your question to give you a complete answer, but I see a major issue with your code: you are trying to assign to a `str` object, but `str` are immutable.

Had you had reported the full traceback you would have noticed something like:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Therefore you have to create a new string starting from the one you have, e.g.:

```
s = 'I like dogs more than mice!'
t = 'cat'
n = 7
u = s[:n] + t + s[n + len(t):]
print(u)
# I like cats more than mice!
```

Answer (score 1):

In python a string is immutable. Furthermore when you do `line[1562] = bre` you're trying to assign a string(`bre`) to a character (`line[1562]`) in another. Fortunately is very simple in python to solve this. A good way to do this is concatenating all previous `line` string with `bre` and after `line` string. Finnaly you assign this to var `line`.
Something like

```
line = line[:1562] + bre + line[1563:]
```

But pay attention, when you do that, your lines inside `data` object dont change. You're just changing a copy of it. If you want to read a file lines and then write it changed in the file, you need to doo something like

```
i = 0
bre = 'newtext'
with open(myfile, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for x,line in enumerate(data):
    if i > 0 and line[98] == '1':
        print 'ok'
        data[x] = line[:1562] + bre + line[1563:]
    i += 1

with open(new_file, 'w') as f
    for line in data:
      f.write(data)
```

Comment: The first statement is not true, strings are immutable in Python, `list` aren't!